# How can I install a legacy bootloader on a Windows EFI system?

Tags: windows, multi-boot, bootloader, uefi

**Background Information / My Reasons:**

- I want to use the [chameleon bootloader](http://chameleon.osx86.hu/) to boot a windows 7
  installation, windows was installed in EFI mode on a GPT partitioned
  disk.
- When chameleon loads I see options of Linux and Windows, If I select
  windows from the chameleon bootloader it complains about some
  mis-configuration in /Boot/BCD.
- Windows will boot fine if I boot the disk in EFI mode but not from
  chameleon.

**My Question:**

How can I have this windows installation boot via both an EFI bootloader and a legacy bootloader?

I probably just need to copy some files onto the disk, maybe from the windows CD, I just don't know how or which ones.

Comment: I don't think Windows can boot to a GPT disk when in BIOS mode.  Unless Chameleon can do EFI, I think you'll need to reinstall Windows in order to do this.  I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is, NO you can't.

- [Here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1L0obnZkzX7aFyWqmx6zS1CrXEH_X9rRJUnBYeWWjJgU/edit#) it stress that If Windows is installed in EFI mode, then you must boot the machine in EFI mode.
- and in "[Chainload non-EFI Linux from EFI Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/732696/chainload-none-efi-linux-from-efi-linux)" it says, no boot managers can chain load from EFI mode to BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, unless it is Your firmware's boot manager or rEFInd boot manager. So chameleon bootloader is out.

The answer to your problem is, if you only need to copy some files, then the easiest solution is to boot from Live-CD, or enable the BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, then boot into whatever Linux system you have, e.g., from USB key. Then mount the NTFS system within Linux, and do your copying.