# Chainload non-EFI Linux from EFI Linux

Tags: linux, boot, grub, efi, syslinux

I read somewhere that it might be possible to boot non-EFI Linux from EFI Linux.

If my EFI Linux is booted by `grub-efi`, and my non-EFI Linux is booted by `extlinux`. How to chainload from `grub-efi` to `extlinux`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the only boot managers that can chain load from EFI mode to BIOS/CSM/legacy mode are:

- Your firmware's boot manager. Details vary greatly from one firmware to another, but in general, you'd hit a function key (or sometimes Esc) early in the boot process.
- My [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) To use this option, you must uncomment the `scanfor` line in `refind.conf` and ensure that `hdbios` is among the options on that line. This option isn't 100% reliable, though; some motherboards don't support it, and even if your firmware does support it, the feature will probably boot only from the first hard disk.